# Reading UTF-16 file in Inno Setup Pascal script

Tags: inno-setup, utf-16, pascalscript

I have an `.inf` file exported from Resource Hacker. The file is in UTF-16 LE encoding.

```
EXTRALARGELEGENDSII_INI TEXTFILE "Data.bin"

LARGEFONTSLEGENDSII_INI TEXTFILE "Data_2.bin"

NORMALLEGENDSII_INI TEXTFILE "Data_3.bin"

THEMES_INI TEXTFILE "Data_4.bin"
```

When I load it using the [`LoadStringFromFile` function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringfromfile):

```pascal
procedure LoadResources;
var
  RESOURCE_INFO: AnsiString;
begin
  LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SKINRESOURCE - INFO.inf'), RESOURCE_INFO);
  Log(String(RESOURCE_INFO));
end;
```

I am getting this in the *Debug Output*:

```
E
```

Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the file you are trying to log is a Windows Unicode (UTF-16LE) Encoded text file.

You can use [iConv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) Command Line and convert your file to Windows UTF-8 Encoded File.

The [`LoadStringFromFile` Support Function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringfromfile) does not load Unicode Strings well and it only supports loading ANSI and UTF-8 Encoded Text Files.

Inno Setup Compiler Debug Output stops logging the Text File because it finds a Character it can't load (NULL) and that's why you're getting only "E" in Compiler Debug Output even `LoadStringFromFile` loads the text file completely.

---

You need to download the Setup Program of the iConv as shown below to get iConv Executable File and some DLLs used to convert between character encoding.

[image]

After downloaded, install GnuWin32 (LibIconv for Windows) and go to the installation folder.

Copy following four files inside the sub directory in installation folder called "bin".

They are:

*libcharset1.dll*

*libiconv2.dll*

*iconv.exe*

*libintl3.dll*

copy these files to the directory where you store files of your Inno Setup Project.

Then use following code to do the Conversion.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "libcharset1.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "iconv.exe"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "libiconv2.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "libintl3.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('iconv.exe');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('libcharset1.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('libintl3.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('libiconv2.dll');
  ShellExec('Open', ExpandConstant('CMD.exe'), ExpandConstant('/C iConv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 < SKINRESOURCE-INFO.inf > SKINRESOURCE-INFO-ANSI.inf'), ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode); 
  DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SKINRESOURCE-INFO.inf'));
```

Now `LoadStringFromFile` should load the text file correctly as now it has the Windows UTF-8 Encoding.

You may also log it after converting it into a Unicode String like `Log(String(RESOURCE_INFO))`, if you are using Unicode Inno Setup.

Comment: Thank You! Works like a Charm!

Comment: 1) Why ANSI? You lose Unicode characters this way. Use UTF-8! 2) And note that ANSI is not the same as Windows-1252. What ANSI encoding is used differs with Windows configuration. So if you explicitly convert to Windows-1252, but you load the file using configured ANSI encoding, you end up with mess, unless the file uses ASCII characters only.  3) You can [use PowerShell to convert encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4817683/850848), no need for a 3rd party tool. But anyway, you do not need even any external tool. You can convert this in a Pascal Script.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl corrected to UTF-8. I forgotten the PowerShell. :-(

Comment: 4) It's not true that `LoadStringFromFile` stops loading the text file when it finds the NULL character. The `LoadStringFromFile` loads the file completely always. It's only the Inno Setup Compiler *Debug Output* pane that stops on the NULL character. See my answer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I asked why `LoadStringFromFile` does not load strings correctly. If you knew a Conversion can be done easily using PowerShell, you should post it with your answer. :-(

Comment: I didn't know that you need to convert this on runtime. From the `ExpandConstant('{tmp}\...')` I (possibly incorrectly) assumed that it's a file temporarily extracted from the installer using `ExtractTemporaryFile`. Hence I assumed that it's your static file, that you can manually convert and embed in UTF-8 encoding to your installer. Had you told us that it's a file created externally, that you have no control over, my answer would be different. But you didn't tell us. How is the file created?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks Anyway. ;-)

Comment: Sorry I forgotten to tell you that isn't a my Static file. Anyway, `iConv` does the Trick well. The file is created via Resource Hacker. The file contains Resource information about a MSSTYLES Skin as it shows lines like `THEMES_INI TEXTFILE "Data_4.bin" `. ;-)

Comment: Do you call the Resource Hacker in your installer to export some resource file?

Comment: Yes you're Right. My Resource Hacker command exports Skin's `TEXTFILE`s whose contain Information about the Skin's colours and fonts. I am doing this because ISSkin.dll uses this Information to load Skin and I can detect WizardForm Caption Font Size etc. WITH SKIN FILE. Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831354/finding-out-inno-setup-wizardform-caption-font-size-font-name-and-font-color

Comment: See my updated answer for a function to load UTF-16 LE file.

Answer (score 5):

The file is in the UTF-16 LE encoding.

The `LoadStringFromFile` does not support any Unicode encoding. It loads the file as is, to a byte array (the `AnsiString` is effectively used as a byte array).

As the Unicode `string` (in [Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) – the only version as of Inno Setup 6) actually uses the UTF-16 LE encoding, all you need to do is to copy the byte array bitwise to the (Unicode) `string`. And trim the [UTF-16 LE BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (`FEFF`).

```pascal
procedure RtlMoveMemory(Dest: string; Source: PAnsiChar; Len: Integer);
  external 'RtlMoveMemory@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function LoadStringFromUTF16LEFile(FileName: string; var S: string): Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
begin
  Result := LoadStringFromFile(FileName, A);
  if Result then
  begin
    SetLength(S, Length(A) div 2);
    RtlMoveMemory(S, A, Length(S) * 2);
    // Trim BOM, if any
    if (Length(S) >= 1) and (Ord(S[1]) = $FEFF) then
      Delete(S, 1, 1);
  end;
end;
```

---

See also:

- [Reading file in Ansi and Unicode encoding in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38968230/850848)
- [How to save a UTF-16 with BOM file with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060076/850848)