# Inno script function "LoadStringFromFile" NOT reading Unicode correctly

Tags: unicode, inno-setup, readfile

I have a Inno script that read a text file "Version.txt" from folders and show the content in a radio format like in the picture below. The problem is instead of showing : "Version 1.0" & "Version 2.0" . It shows a text like "yBC" & "yBC" Which is incomprehensible. How can I correct the code to read the unicode format from the text file ?

[image: Picture]

```
  if ((FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) <> 0) and
     (FindRec.Name <> '.') and
     (FindRec.Name <> '..') then
  begin
    Path := RootPath + '\' + FindRec.Name;
    { LoadStringFromFile can handle only ascii/ansi files, no Unicode }
    if LoadStringFromFile(Path + '\' + 'Version.txt', Name) then
    begin
      Dirs.Add(Path);
      DirCheckListBox.AddRadioButton(Name, '', 0, False, True, nil);
      { If already installed, check the path that was selected previously, }
      { otherwise check the first one }
      if (DirCheckListBox.Items.Count = 1) or
         (CompareText(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text, Path) = 0) then
      begin
        DirCheckListBox.ItemIndex := DirCheckListBox.Items.Count - 1;
        DirCheckListBox.Checked[DirCheckListBox.ItemIndex] := True;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Where's nothing like *"unicode format"*. Unicode is **character set**. We need to know what **encoding** does your file have. If the file uses Unicode character set, it may have UTF-8, UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE encodings (or even yet another). UTF-8 can be with and without BOM.

Comment: If you do not know, try to open the file in Windows Notepad using various encodings. Windows Notepad uses a wrong terminology, so there "Unicode" = UTF-16LE, "Unicode big endian" = UTF-16BE.

Comment: I opened the text tile and clicked on Save As, in the "Encoding" there was "unicode" alone

Comment: I mean in the Open dialog: So, if you select "Unicode" there, the file opens correctly? While if you select "Unicode big endian" or UTF-8 it probably opens incorrectly, right?

Comment: The file opens correctly in all options (ANSI, unicode ...) options

Comment: I do not think that's actually possible.

Comment: Can you ZIP the file and upload it somewhere for us to check?

Comment: Yeah sure. Here is one the files: https://files.fm/u/w692fwfr

Comment: It's UTF-16LE. And I have no problem reading it using `LoadStringFromUTF16LEFile` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39845057/850848

Comment: This is what I get if I put your file to the folders and replace `LoadStringFromFile` call with `LoadStringFromUTF16LEFile` and change `Name` variable type from `AnsiString` to `string`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYwVH.png - All assuming you are using Unicode version of Inno Setup.

Comment: Thank you Martin,

Comment: So did you resolve it?

Comment: Unfortunately No, that solution didn't work for me and I still get a text like "ybV1" instead of 1.0

Comment: Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: The problem is defining the problem. I do not know what your problem is. For me everything works. Do you have Unicode version of Inno Setup?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by Unicode version of Inno Setup ? Are there multiple versions of Inno Setup ? 

I downloaded Inno Setup from jrsoftware org. I didn't see any other version there.

Comment: You are right, the problem is in defining the problem. I am still very new to Inno script but not new to programming in general. I am still struggling to understand some parts..

Comment: Yes, there are two versions: Legacy Ansi version and Unicode version. See http://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php

Comment: lol that was there the whole time!!  but I didn't see it !  Sorry Martin for the trouble. You wee and are very helpful and patient. Thank you. I will check it out and then reply.