# How to save a UTF-16 with BOM file with Inno Setup

Tags: unicode, inno-setup, pascalscript

How to save a string to a text file with UTF-16 (UCS-2) encoding with BOM?

The `SaveStringsToUTF8File` saves as UTF-8.

Using streams saves it as ANSI.

```pascal
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to length(aString) do begin
    Stream.write(aString[i],1);
    Stream.write(#0,1);
  end;
  stream.free;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Unicode `string` (in the [Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) – the only version as of Inno Setup 6) actually uses the UTF-16 LE encoding, all you need to do is to copy the (Unicode) `string` to a byte array (`AnsiString`) bit-wise. And add the [UTF-16 LE BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (`FEFF`):

```pascal
procedure RtlMoveMemoryFromStringToPtr(Dest: PAnsiChar; Source: string; Len: Integer);
  external 'RtlMoveMemory@kernel32.dll stdcall';
  
function SaveStringToUFT16LEFile(FileName: string; S: string): Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
begin
  S := #$FEFF + S; 
  SetLength(A, Length(S) * 2);
  RtlMoveMemoryFromStringToPtr(A, S, Length(S) * 2);
  Result := SaveStringToFile(FileName, A, False);
end;
```

---

This is just an opposite of: [Inno Setup Pascal Script - Reading UTF-16 file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39844156/850848#39845057).